# How to pip install tkinter

Tags: python

I use pip install python-tk
but have an error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-tk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-tk

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: what OS, what python version?

Comment: If you are on Linux you probably want to install tkinter using `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` or similar for your distro (you may need to search for the exact name of the package but it should be there)

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip

Answer (score 12):

Tkinter isn't distributed through pip; if it didn't come pre-packaged with Python, you have to get it from elsewhere:

- Ubuntu

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

- Fedora

```bash
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```

- MacOS

```bash
brew install python-tk
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, check this checkbox during setup.

[image]

Answer (score -7):

Firstly Make sure Python and pip is preinstalled on your system.
Type the following commands in command prompt to check is python and pip is installed on your system.

To check Python:

`python --version`

If python is successfully installed, the version of python installed on your system will be displayed.

To check pip

`pip -V`

The version of pip will be displayed, if it is successfully installed on your system.

Now Install Tkinter

Tkinter can be installed using pip. The following command is run in the command prompt to install Tkinter.

`pip install tk`

This command will start downloading and installing packages related to the Tkinter library. Once done, the message of successful installation will be displayed.

Comment: The package `tk` is not tkinter, it's tensorkit. You can't install tkinter with pip.

Comment: pip cannot install tkinter